# Is scroll position the same on every screen?

Tags: javascript, html, css, scroll, fixed

Quick question here:

will `$(this).scrollTop()` value be equivalent on every screen when the bottom of a fixed position div meets the bottom of an adjacent relative positioned div (a div scrolling upward with the rest of the screen)?

Getting the scroll position when a fixed point meets a scrolling point is a bit of trial an error. It would be good to know if that value is good for javascript on every device.

Comment: I think this depends on wether the page's height is affected by screen's size (responsive design). If you need to compare two element's position, compare calculated `scrollTop()` or `position().top` of both elements.

Comment: Brilliance: conducted through an alternating current - that's my story and I'm sticking to it. &#128522

Comment: Does [this](https://codesandbox.io/s/unruffled-waterfall-21slr?file=/index.html) demonstrate the problem you're having?

Comment: It demonstrates the challenge, which is to change styling of, say, green div when its bottom point passes bottom of fuscia div (with scroll value displayed). Solved previously like this: `if (y >= x - k && y < z - c) { $('.name').removeClass('q').addClass('v');}`, where `y = $(this).scrollTop();` Wanted to ensure this works on all browsers, as k and c come through trial and error. Followed deltazero's advice, and tried something like this `if(bottom_green >= bottom_red){etc..]`, where bottom_red is fixed and values calculated as he suggested. This turned out a bit sketchy, and I left it as is.